# Reset jackson JsonSerializer to default in subclass

Tags: java, json, jackson, overriding, serialization

I have a base class that looks like

```
@JsonSerialize(using = BaseClassSerializer.class)
public class BaseClass {
   ...
}
```

And a SubClass that looks like

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
}
```

I do not want to use the `BaseClassSerializer` in `SubClass`, but instead revert to the default jackson serializer for `SubClass`. I know I can override the Serializer, but I want all the default serialization rules to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [`None`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.None.html) serializer on your derived class, which is Jackson's default serializer.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonSerializer.None.class)
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
}
```